# error building h2o steam binary: lib/yarn/yarn.go:22:2: cannot find package "context" in any of:

Tags: go, hadoop-yarn, h2o

while following the [dev setup guide](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) for h2o steam I encounter this error:

[image]

as text

`➜  steam git:(master) pwd
/Users/m/workspace/go-workspace/src/github.com/h2oai/steam
➜  steam git:(master) make
go build
lib/yarn/yarn.go:22:2: cannot find package "context" in any of:
    /Users/m/workspace/go-workspace/src/github.com/h2oai/steam/vendor/context (vendor tree)
    /usr/local/go/src/context (from $GOROOT)
    /Users/m/workspace/go-workspace/src/context (from $GOPATH)
make: *** [build] Error 1`

how can I run `make` successfully?

Comment: Use Go 1.7.1 or higher as stated in the [developer instructions](https://github.com/h2oai/steam/blob/master/DEVEL.md).

Answer (score 1):

updating go to `go1.7.1` resolved the issue. to update, follow the instructions at golang.org to:

- [uninstall the old version of go](https://golang.org/doc/install#uninstall)
- [install the latest version of go](https://golang.org/doc/install)